# Printing out a 2d array in a specific format in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

So basically when i print my array it looks like this:

```
      P00       P01       P02      
      P10       P11       P12       
      P20       P21       P22
```

I want it to look like this:

```
             M[0][0]   M[0][1]   M[0][2]   
      M[0][0] P00       P01       P02       
      M[1][0] P10       P11       P12      
      M[2][0] P20       P21       P22
```

My code:

```
 for (z=0; z<N; z++){

              for (c=0; c<N;c++){
                printf("\t%p", &M[z][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
          }
```

Note that Pxx is the pointer address

Comment: For portable code, use `printf("\t%p", (void *) &M[z][c]);`  Add cast if `M[][]` is not all ready a `void *`.

Comment: One thing though, those are not proper indices for a matrix. You're stating that everything in every row/column is that matrix point when the coordinates that you've given are all relevant to one location in the matrix itself.(0,0) != (0,1). You'd have to place the location at every point basically the way that your Pxx Statements are placed throughout. Basically. Instead of placing two points in your M[x][x] Just place one as an index m[Var]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("\tM[0][%d]",i);
    }        
    printf("\n");
for (z=0; z<N; z++){
    printf("M[%d][0]",z);
    for (c=0; c<N;c++){

        printf(" %p\t", &M[z][c]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

above outer loop :

```
printf("\t\tM[0][0]\tM[0][1]\tM[0][2]\n");
```

and then just below outer loop  :

```
printf("M[%d][0]\t",i);
```

Look like this:

```
printf("\t\t");

for (z=0; z<N; z++)
  printf("\tM[0][%d]",z);

printf("\n");

for ( z=0; z<N; z++){
   printf("M[%d][0]\t",z);
   for(c=0; c<N; c++){
      printf("\t%p",&M[z][c]);
   }
   printf("\n");
 }
```